# Select query for posgres database using php

Tags: php, postgresql

I'm trying to write SELECT query for Postgres database but not I'm getting some error - 
pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$" LINE 1

```
$findResult = pg_query('SELECT * FROM fingerprintdata WHERE buildingname = $building  ');
$numrows    = pg_num_rows($findResult);
```

Comment: _Don't_ concatenate your query together, instead use prepared statements.

Comment: your table name is lower case as you suggested here - fingerprintdata?

Answer (score 0):

The query should be like this:

```
pg_query('SELECT * FROM fingerprintdata WHERE buildingname = "$building"  ');
```

the variable should be inside quotes ""

Answer (score 0):

```
$findResult = pg_query($conn, 'SELECT * FROM fingerprintdata WHERE buildingname = "$building"');
$numrows = pg_num_rows($findResult);
```

Comment: Thanks Silentfox, i'm trying your edited query but getting this error- pg_query() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given

Answer (score 0):

Please try below solution. You have not put equal sign in single quote that's why you get the error of variable.

```
$findResult = pg_query('SELECT * FROM fingerprintdata WHERE buildingname =' . $building);
$numrows    = pg_num_rows($findResult);
```

Comment: Can you suggest me if i want to add multiple where clause then what will be the statement? E.g.  $findResult = pg_query("SELECT * FROM fingerprintdata WHERE buildingname = '".trim($building)."' ,floorlevel = '".trim($floor)."' ;");

Comment: use and in between. Also valid the answer plz if it's helpful

Comment: It's very helpful. Thanks Craig

Comment: mean to say flag up to my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM fingerprintdata WHERE buildingname = '.pg_escape_literal($building); // to be able to var_dump($query) to see, what it actually looks like
$findResult = pg_query($query);
```

In Your case, You are using single quotes, which do not expand `$building` inside. It would work if You used double quotes, but You would be vulnerable to SQL injection (for example `$building = "xxx'; DROP DATABASE ...";`)